# RC debouncer circuit does not work

Tags: debounce, toggle-switch

I tried two circuits below, neither of them seems to be working (I used a 74LS04 and a 74LS00); the output doesn't change when I press the switch.

I found that the voltage at point "A" doesn't drop below 0.8 V (stays around 2 V) when the switch is pressed.

I guess the reason is that when the switch is pressed, the capacitor starts to discharge, but there is a also a current flow out of the logic gate to ground through R2, causing a voltage drop across R2, so that the voltage at A can not reach logic "0".

Are there any other ways to make this work?

[image]

R1 = 80 kΩ
R2 = 20 kΩ
C = 1 μF

[image]

Comment: Please give the values for R1, R2 and the cap.

Comment: R1=80K, R2=20K, C = 1uF (the first chart)

Comment: The 74LSxx parts are bipolar TTL logic.  The inputs source current, and you must draw about 0.4 mA from the input for the input to be seen as a Low.  20K for R2 is much too high a value.

Comment: As peter says, those values are pretty crazy. I'd do something like 10k for R1, 100ohm for R2 and 100nF for the cap. 1u is fine but 100n is enough.

Answer (score 2):

Refering to the first circuit diagram:

If \$V_A\$ stays too high when button is pressed, \$R_2\$ obviously is too large.

So you have to decrease \$R_2\$.

If that in turn decreases your time constant \$\tau=(R_1 + R_2)C\$ too much for the circuit to work properly (i.e. debounce properly) you have too increase \$R_1\$ and/or \$C\$ in addition.

BTW: You wouldn't have this problem if you used CMOS logic (74HC04 or better  74HC14) which has very high impedance inputs (i.e. practically no current is coming from the input).

Comment: R2 can be removed.

Comment: @Vladimir Cravero: Probably, yes. That'd be the extreme of decreasing R2.

Comment: I meant that for real. There's no particular reason for R2 to be there, unless you wanna limit the current through the switch.

Comment: I'm not dissenting in any way.

Comment: If you remove R2 or too small, will it cause fast discharge, voltage spike, not good?

Comment: Yes, it will discharge fast. It will cause a current spike (no voltage spike). If the capacitor is small (e.g. <1µF) and the total energy stored is small that won't be a problem though.

Comment: The reason for R2 is the longevity of the switch. Shorting out a charged capacitor is not, in general, good for the lifetime of a mechanical switch. For some switch constructions, even a single discharge of a cap can affect switch performance.

Comment: That may be the reason for R2 but I think the energy stored in a few 10nF can't hurt much even if R2 is close to 0.

Comment: Energy is small but the ESR on ceramic capacitors is very low so instantaneous current can be quite high. I wouldn't be surprised if the  current was in the Amps. Best to add significant resistance like 100 Ohms. Limits instantaneous current to 50 mA for 5V supply which is max rating for many tactile switches.

Comment: Max. rating is for continuous current. What counts in this case is total energy. Assume that all the energy of a 100nF capacitor charged to 5V goes into a tiny volume of only 0.1mm x 0.1mm x 0.1mm copper: the temperature will just rise by <0.4°C.

Comment: You do not want it to discharge fast, you want it to attenuate on both the rising and the falling edge. And still a Schmitt-trigger is needed.

Answer (score 2):

I did these circuits a couple of times and they are working perfectly. The little details matter! Like that Schmitt Trigger function!

- If it is not a Schmitt Trigger (inverter), it will not work!

[image]
<sub>Original Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Nv8.jpg</sub>

Comment: This doesn't answer the asked question. It surely can work without Schmitt Trigger. And the original circuit did not work because the resistances are completely unsuitable for LS TTL. So in your circuit with non-LS TTL. Your circuit on the right likely won't work either with 10k pull-down and 7414 TTL IC.

Comment: -I actually used 74HC14 and not 7414. 


-I am presenting here my working setup for debouncing buttons.

Comment: Well it does not read HC so how can we know what you mean if you simply say 7414.

Comment: It will work without a Schmitt trigger. However you will never be able to accurately predict up and low time without a Schmitt trigger. 2/ You should always add a resistor between the switch and the input, to protect the input.

Comment: @Fredled From what the resistor would protect, why it is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that first circuit works with the 74LS14 Schmitt-trigger inverter when you use 1 kΩ for both R1 and R2 and 1 μF for C (and 4.7 μF is more reliable).

By the way, the first schematic comes from [this white paper](https://my.eng.utah.edu/%7Ecs5780/debouncing.pdf) which has a lot more discussion about the selection of the resistors. However, it doesn't offer any particular values.

I have been looking for a practical solution for the normal TTL logic levels, and it has been so frustrating that I now venture to say that nobody has been able to actually do it for 74LSxx TTL logic inputs. There is [a short video from TI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1-kc04jSE4) saying that you need the Schmitt-trigger, and if they say so, I believe them, especially because I could not find any combination of R and C that would work, also, attempt to use the switch tied to low and trigger to high, didn't make a difference. Nothing would work.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that your circuit was never going to work, even with zero input currents. 20k/80k will give a high input voltage of 1 volt. So let's start over.

Your problem is I(IL), the input current required to pull the input voltage below V(IL). If you look at a data sheet https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls04.pdf
, you'll see that I(IL) is 0.4 ma (max), and V(IL) is 0.8 v (min). Applying Ohm's law, you see that R2 must be less than 2k. Let's set it to 1k.
Now, we need R1 low enough to pull the input high. V(IH) is nominally 2 volts, so let's go for 2.5 volts. Then R1 must be 1k as well.
Originally, the time constant (R1 + R2)C was 0.1. To get this with the new resistors, you need C at 50 uF.
Peak discharge current through the switch is only 7.5 ma, so this is certainly reasonable. It will be a pretty big cap physically,though.

Let me introduce you to another approach, using a SPDT switch instead of a SPST switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy5S6V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This starts with the switch in the position shown, and the output high. Pushing the button first releases the upper (NC) contact, but the output does not change. When the common (C) contacts the lower (NO) contact, the SR flip-flop made by the two gates switches, and the output goes low. Contact bounce on the NO contact has no effect on the output, as long as the common does not bounce so far that it makes contact with the NC contact, and this is a VERY good assumption. When the button is released, it happens in reverse.

The parts tradeoff is adding one gate while eliminating one capactor. The advantage is that there is no need to worry about the capacitor size, since the operation of the debouncer does not depend on time constants at all.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvATSe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R2 should be after C1. This way, C1 will be emptied almost immediately on key press, bringing the input to zero volt almost as fast (R2 + input capacitance will slow a little bit, in the range of microseconds).

Upon key release, C1 will load up gradually. Set C1 value according to the time you wish the input to stay low on key press.

You can add a diode from ground to SW1 IN, if you notice negative current.

Comment: Why? That will just discharge the cap with fast and large current spike, likely degrading the switch and capacitor in the long run, and causing an EMI pulse on each discharge. I also understand there is no single one way that fits all, but I always find these solutions that short a capacitor through a pushbutton a bit cheap and hobbyist-grade. The R2 is practically useless, it will not delay in range of microseconds, but 10 nanoseconds. Assumed input capacitance of 10pF, from Onsemi 74HC14 data sheet.

Comment: @Justme The resistors are there precisely to mitigate the "large current spike" and the various bouncing effects. It shouldn't be always 1uF. 0.1uF will be enough with a good switch. As a rule, I never put an input in direct contact with a switch and every example of debouncing I have seen add this resistor. If you are really afraid of degradation of the switch and the cap, you can add a 1K resistor between the cap and the switch. (Then we have something similar to the original schematic.) I agree that it can be better.

Comment: Yes if you put a resistor between button and cap, there will be no large currents anywhere and the cap will smooth bouncing effects when it is directly on the input pin. Which means the series resistor on input is not needed because the source of the problems was eliminated by moving the resistor into better place.

Comment: @Justme Yes but you are limited in the value of this resistor. If resistance to ground is too high, you have the problem mentioned in this post. The button will have to be pressed too long to take effect. It depends on how long the user can wait (or should wait because it can be useful to force the user to wait and to press longer).

Comment: But same applies the other way too, if the component values are poorly chosen, it will limit how often you can push the button even if it detects it immediately. So you anyway need to select the resistors and capacitors according to how long or short or how repeated button presses are required. So it depends what the button is used for and why it even needs to be debounced. Usually debouncing is simply used to remove bouncy contacts, plus some margin due to aging and wear of the button. The rest of the timing could anyway be done in software if required, or with different HW.